# Using Right Join and WHERE IN Clause

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

Consider these models

```
class SearchableText(models.Model):
    searchable_text = models.TextField()

class SearchTerm(models.Model):
    searchabletext = models.ForeignKey(SearchableText, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    term = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I want to write equivalent of this sql statement using django orm

```
Select SearchableText.* right join SearchTerm on SearchTerm.searchabletext=SearchableText.id where SearchTerm.term in ("term 1","term 2","term 3")
```

I also want to order the result based on number of matched terms, but I guess it would entitle another question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Q` function. I think this might be the query you are looking for:

```
from django.db.models import Q, F

SearchableText.objects.filter(Q(id=F('searchterm__searchabletext')), searchterm__term__in=['term1', 'term2', 'term3'])
```

The generated SQL query is like this:

```
SELECT app_searchabletext.* FROM app_searchabletext INNER JOIN app_searchterm ON (app_searchabletext.id = app_searchterm.searchabletext_id) WHERE (app_searchabletext.id = (app_searchterm.searchabletext_id) AND app_searchterm.term IN (term1, term2, term3))
```